# what type of gas masks are effective against fumes of muriatic acid?

Tags: protection

Some pool cleaning activities utilize a substantial amount of muriatic acid. The fume from this is quite dangerous. What should one look for in a mask that protects against the fume? What type of clothing is recommended?

Comment: Really , quite dangerous? We use muriatic to etch concrete, balance swimming pool PH , how is it quite dangerous? No gas masks are required for most of the usages! A rare down vote Btw.

Comment: @EdBeal I have used it for PH balancing at about 1/2 gallon by just avoiding he fumes. That I can handle. But I saw someone use 15 gallons in 3 hours to clean a pool, he had a mask but did not use it. It just did not look safe to me.

Comment: @EdBeal If you've never gotten a whiff of 34% MA fumes, then you're lucky. It's not pleasant, and it's absolutely not good for you. For one of many easily found examples, see https://www.doityourself.com/stry/10-muriatic-acid-safety-tips

Comment: @gene I have used muriatic acid thousands of times and you may even find close to 50 answers or comments on this site from me on using muriatic to etch. There are many things that are not good for you concrete when wet on your skin is not good for you. Bleach is not good for you. Yes if you sniff an open bottle it’s not good but having used it many thousands of times with NO ppe it is not required. Do you need a mask to use or dilute it safely? NO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muriatic Acid is the trade name for diluted hydrochloric acid (HCL). So, basically *hydrogen chloride* in water. You need a respirator that will handle *hydrogen chloride*; look at those labeled for use with *acid gases* and make sure that HC is listed, such as this one:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your question, but the answer to the entire category of your question is consult the [MSDS (Materials Safety Data Sheet)](https://www.aquaticspecialtyservices.com/msds/MuriaticHydrochloric.pdf).  Manufacturers are legally required to make them available and you will be able to find the precautions necessary for your specific product.  I'll let you surf the datasheet or look up the one for your brand.

Never mind, I couldn't resist.  For the brand I've linked:

"Wear rubber gloves and eye protection when handling. Goggles should be vapor proof. Wash hands after handling. Provide ventilation for storage and use areas. Wear impervious clothing when handling and using this product. Do not breathe vapor. Avoid contact with skin and clothing."

Comment: This is a better answer because osha doesn't require a mask but gloves and face shield are.